# Show negatives in Red in Plotly and R

Tags: r, plotly

[image]I want to show the negatives as red colour

Tried to look for solutions online but none found

```
plot_ly(x = ecomm_yoy2$YOY, y = ecomm_yoy2$Brand, type = 'bar', orientation = 'h') %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "% YOY change in £ for June", dtick = 10)) %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(categoryorder = "array", categoryarray = ecomm_yoy2$YOY)) %>%
  add_annotations(text = ecomm_yoy2$YOY, showarrow = F, xshift = 25)
```

Currently only shows blue[image]

Comment: Can you please add the result of `dput(ecomm_yoy2)`?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample from your dataset using `dput()`? It's easier to reproduce the example then, type `?dput()` in the console & hit `enter` to get to know the usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using plotly's `color` and `colors` arguments:

```
ecomm_yoy2 <- data.frame(YOY = -19:20, Brand = 1:40)

plot_ly(ecomm_yoy2, x = ~YOY, y = ~Brand, type = 'bar', orientation = 'h', color = ~YOY < 0, colors = c("chartreuse3", "red"), name = ~ifelse(YOY < 0, "< 0", ">= 0")) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "% YOY change in £ for June", dtick = 10)) %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(categoryorder = "array", categoryarray = ~YOY)) %>%
  add_annotations(text = ~YOY, showarrow = F, xshift = 25)
```

[image: Result]

You might want to have a look at:

```
library(plotly)
library(listviewer)
schema(jsonedit = interactive())
```

which let's you navigate through plotly's available traces and their arguments.

Comment: Thanks - this kind of worked but I wouldn't want the legend showing.  And it also messes the order up?  I will post a new pic and edit.

Comment: You can use `%>% layout(showlegend = FALSE)` to hide the legend. Concerning the order please provide us with some example data showing the problem.

Comment: Actually I hadn't included the name part in the code and it seems without that the order doesn't work.  So now fixed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do it is:

1. Calculate a new variable with positive values as '1' & negative values as '0' and attach it to the dataset.
2. While plotting, use color aesthetic to color the bars, according to the values of the column that was just created.