# R plotly bar chart positive/negative values different color second axis

Tags: r, plotly, bar-chart, r-plotly

So from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57073397/show-negatives-in-red-in-plotly-and-r) Im trying to make a plotly bar chart on the second y-axis with negative values depicted as red and posiive values as green....but somehow the colors are still wrong....why?

```
    t <- tibble("one" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
              "two" = c(-5,6,9,-8,7,-1,5,2,1),
              "three" = c(2,5,6,9,8,7,8,4,5))
  
  Plot <- 
    
    plot_ly(t, x = ~one, y = ~three, type = 'scatter',  mode = 'lines',
            name = "three", line = list(color = "#ffc107")
    ) 
  
  Plot <- Plot %>% 
    add_trace(x = ~one, y = ~two, type = 'bar', name = "two",   
              color = ~two < 0, colors = c("#28a745", "#dc3545"),
              yaxis = 'y2'
    ) %>% 
    
    layout(title = "test",
           xaxis = list(titel = "one"), 
           yaxis = list(side = 'left', title = 'two', 
                        showgrid = F, zeroline = F,
                        showline = T),
           yaxis2 = list(side = 'right', overlaying = "y", 
                         title = 'three', 
                         showgrid = F, zeroline = F, 
                         showline = T))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of `colors` in the `plot_ly()` call (`NULL` in your example) is recycled in `add_trace()` if you don't prevent it.

Please check the following:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

t <- tibble("one" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
            "two" = c(-5,6,9,-8,7,-1,5,2,1),
            "three" = c(2,5,6,9,8,7,8,4,5))

# 'bar' objects don't have these attributes: 'mode', 'line'
Plot <- plot_ly(t, x = ~one, y = ~two, type = 'bar', name = ~ifelse(two < 0, yes = "two < 0", no = "two > 0"),   
            color = ~two < 0, colors = c("#28a745", "#dc3545"),
            yaxis = 'y'
  ) %>% add_trace(t, x = ~one, y = ~three, type = 'scatter',  mode = 'lines',
              name = "three", line = list(color = "#ffc107"), color = NULL, yaxis = "y2"
              
  ) %>% layout(title = "test",
         xaxis = list(titel = "one"),
         yaxis = list(side = 'right', 
                       title = 'three', 
                       showgrid = F, zeroline = F, 
                       showline = T),
         yaxis2 = list(side = 'left', title = 'two', 
                       showgrid = F, zeroline = F,
                       showline = T, overlaying = "y"))

Plot
```

[image: result]

---

**Edit** as requested below:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

t <- tibble("one" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
            "two" = c(-5,6,9,-8,7,-1,5,2,1),
            "three" = c(2,5,6,9,8,7,8,4,5))

# 'bar' objects don't have these attributes: 'mode', 'line'
Plot <- plot_ly(t, x = ~one, y = ~three, type = 'scatter',  mode = 'lines',
                name = "three", line = list(color = "#ffc107"), color = NULL, yaxis = "y") %>%
  add_trace(t, x = ~one, y = ~two, type = 'bar', mode = NULL, line = NULL, name = ~ifelse(two < 0, yes = "two < 0", no = "two > 0"),   
                 color = ~two < 0, colors = c("#28a745", "#dc3545"),
                 yaxis = 'y2') %>%
  layout(title = "test",
             xaxis = list(titel = "one"),
             yaxis = list(side = 'right', 
                          title = 'three', 
                          showgrid = F, zeroline = F, 
                          showline = T),
             yaxis2 = list(side = 'left', title = 'two', 
                           showgrid = F, zeroline = F,
                           showline = T, overlaying = "y"),
         hovermode = "x unified")

Plot
```

Comment: thx! So is there also a way to first determine the line and 2ndly the bar chart? Cause now when I hover over the plot via hovermode = "x unified" in layout the bar chart value is given first and the line value 2nd

Comment: Sure, this can be done. Please see my edit. However, than the line is partly covered by the bar, which in my eyes seems unfavorable as doing it vice versa.

Comment: yeah indeed, why isnt the call "overlaying = n" not working? ... Moreover I do get this error: Warning messages:
1: In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(N, "Set2") :
  minimal value for n is 3, returning requested palette with 3 different levels

2: In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(N, "Set2") :
  minimal value for n is 3, returning requested palette with 3 different levels

Comment: Btw I added a date-range with add_trace and want to have it in white but its also depicted in red/green...why? .....see you code which I edited

Comment: oh wait I didnt do the edit...one sec :)

Comment: Please ask a new question with a proper example and link it here instead of trying to add new aspects to this one.

Comment: Done! See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71006568/r-plotly-show-x-axis-value-via-hoovermode