# Chart with secondary y-axis with values positive and negative where the variable in the secondary y-axis changes

Tags: r, plotly

Continuation from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70576618/r-plotly-bar-chart-positive-negative-values-different-color-second-axis/70590015#70590015?newreg=0df8984d32fc433fa9043be9ee1c41d2) I am trying to make a plotly bar chart on the second y-axis with negative values depicted as red and positive values as green. Now I want the same chart with dynamic secondary y-axis ( the values of the secondary changes ). If all values of y become positive then it should show bars in green and if all values become negative then it should show bars in red. I am not able to plot this. The color palette is changing for (i) all positive y values and (ii) all negative y values.

I want the color of the bars correct.